# iOS 10, alpha ignored

Tags: ios

I have a custom view. In `initWithFrame:` I have:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:0.8];
```

Works on iOS < 10, Doesn't work on iOS 10, alpha ignored and view is just white. 
How to make color transparent on iOS 10 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 10 does not clip the color components to 1. So it tries to draw (255, 255, 255, 0.8) instead of (1, 1, 1, 0.8) as an older version of iOS would. Try:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.8];
```